# How to automatically turn variable name to a string value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to implement a reusable helper function which can change the name of a variable to string value. For example, I have some parameters, the function will print which one is empty:

```
paramsHandler(name, address, mobileNum, ...){
  if(!name){
    console.log("name cannot be empty");
  }
  if(!address){
    console.log("address cannot be empty");
  }  
  if(!mobileNum){
    console.log("mobileNum cannot be empty");
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, I want to make it generalized, something like below, where key should be the string of the parameter name.

```
paramsHandler(...params){
  for(const key of params){
      if(!key){
         console.log("key cannot be empty");
      }
  }
}
```

Do anyone knows how could I do this?

Comment: _"...where key should be the string of the parameter name"_ - You don't have named parameters in that example. `params` is an array. So the best you can get is an index.

Comment: You can examine the `arguments` object, but when you use the `... params` form then the parameters *have no names*.

Comment: @Pointy neither do the items in `arguments`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, of course; if the formal parameters aren't named, then the best one can do is complain by position. The whole point of this question is unclear.